# VirtualBox port forwarding preventing port binding on host

Tags: docker, virtualbox, portforwarding

I have a NodeJS server running within a Docker container. I'm using Docker Toolbox for this, therefore I have a VirtualBox VM that I'm running my container in. My server needs to use a dgram websocket to bind to 0.0.0.0:3000 on the host and listen for data packets there, so I set up port forwarding from 3000->3000 in VirtualBox.

The problem is, when I try and run the applications on the host that are supposed to be publishing data to port 3000, they are not able to bind to the port.

The error I get is:

```
{ Error: bind EACCES 0.0.0.0:3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at _handle.lookup (dgram.js:219:18)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'bind',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 3000 }
```

If I shut down the VM and run my server outside of the container everything works fine.

I have my server set up so that it does not have exclusive binding set and reuseAddr is set to true when the websocket is created. This is why when I run it outside of the container there are no binding problems.

My question is: does port forwarding in VirtualBox do some sort of exclusive binding on the forwarded port? If so, can this be disabled? How can I run my server in a container if this happens?

UPDATE:
I have discovered this only happens when I set VirtualBox to use UDP forwarding. TCP does not cause the issue. Is there any way to do UDP port forwarding and still be able to do port binding?